# Create and redirect subdomain for a parked domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, subdomain

I have a domain `parked.com` which is parked onto `real.com`.

I have created the subdomain `m.parked.com` by editing `parked.com`'s named file:

```
m 14400 IN A  ip-address
www.m 14400 IN A  ip-address
```

This works somewhat: if I go to `m.parked.com` it redirects to `http://m.parked.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi`

This is my question:

I would like to redirect this subdomain to `real.com` as that is the domain it is parked on. I do not know how to do this as `parked.com` does not have its own .htaccess file, etc. (due to it being a parked domain) so I can't do any mod_rewrite magic.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

EDIT: Clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue.

1. Edit `parked.com`'s DNS record so it has a subdomain: `m 14400 IN A  ip-address`
2. Add `m.parked.com` to `real.com`'s `ServerAlias` in `httpd.conf`
3. Restart both `Bind` and `Apache`
4. Going to `m.parked.com` will now bring you to `real.com`
5. You can then use `real.com`'s `.htaccess` for your normal URL rewriting.